# Web worker importScripts DOMException script failed to load

Tags: javascript, service-worker, progressive-web-apps, web-worker

I'm trying to use `importScripts`

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', event => {
  ...
  self.importScripts('idb.js');
  ...
}
```

to load a library for a service worker for a PWA but keep getting

```
DOMException: Failed to execute 'importScripts' on 'WorkerGlobalScope': 
    The script at 'http://localhost:3000/idb.js' failed to load.
```

The script file is there, content type is correct, `application/javascript`, and I've tried it with `text/javascript` too. My developer tools network tab shows the request starting and then failing really quickly, not getting a chance to hit the server. The status code is `(failed) net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` when over http and `(failed) net::ERR_FAILED` over https. Any help appreciated

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/10/tweaks-to-addAll-importScripts

> Prior to Chrome 71, calling importScripts() asynchronously outside of the install handler would work. Starting with Chrome 71, those calls throw a runtime exception (unless the same URL was previously imported in an install handler), matching the behavior in other browsers.

I have to move `importScripts` to the top level of my file or my install handler and it works

Answer (score 4):

Also, if there is an `import` statement inside *any of the scripts on which* you are using `importScripts()`, you will get this error, and it will not immediately be clear why.

Answer (score 1):

> Based upon the link you provided, you are not running under HTTPS. You need a site under HTTPS to use a service worker.

My original post wrong. @kmanzana pointed out that localhost is considered a "secure origin".

Comment: "Service workers are only available to "secure origins" (HTTPS sites, basically)...http://localhost is also considered a secure origin" from https://www.chromium.org/blink/serviceworker/service-worker-faq

Comment: I just checked to make sure and served this file over ngrok with https and I'm still seeing the same problem

Comment: Well TIL. What is the status code you receive when you fetch? Are you able to see the response when you directly navigate?

Comment: actually, status code was `(failed) net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` when over http and over https it is `(failed) net::ERR_FAILED`.  I'm able to see the response with navigation or curl yes

Comment: Well I apologize. I attempted to recreate locally with both HTTPS and HTTP but I was unsuccessful.

Comment: Thanks for the attempt. I should've included more code in the context.  It's because I'm not doing this inside fetch event listener, not before/during install.  I'll answer my question